# Creating A Scrollable Level Selector(AndEngine)

Tags: java, android, andengine

i am having troubles with my level selector. i am using the code i found on a tutorial on this forum but it isnt working correct.

The fact is i have two scene's i am using when the user mashes play i set the engine to the second scene and then the user can scroll through the levels.

Then when the user presses the back button i set the camera back to its initial position by saving the position before i leave and then setting it back using camer.setCenter(x,y);

Once the user then goes back to the leve selector scene it doesnt worry correctly. When the user scrolls it scrolls off the screen and doesn't work as it shoud.

Here is my code. If some one has a better way PLEASE feel free to share with me.

```
   @Override
            public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    clickDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);
                    surfaceScrollDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);

           return true;
            }









                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStarted(ScrollDetector pScollDetector,
                                    int pPointerID, float pDistanceX, float pDistanceY) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                distanceX = 0;

                    }




                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(ScrollDetector pScollDetector, int pPointerID,
                                    float pDistanceX, float pDistanceY) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            camera.offsetCenter(-pDistanceX, 0);

                distanceX += pDistanceX;
                    }




                    @Override
                    public void onScrollFinished(ScrollDetector pScollDetector,
                                    int pPointerID, float pDistanceX, float pDistanceY) {
                             if ((distanceX > TURN_PAGE_DISTANCE) && (page > 0))
                 {

                         page--;
                         camera.offsetCenter(distanceX - CAMERA_WIDTH, 0);
                 }
                 else if ((distanceX < -TURN_PAGE_DISTANCE) && (page < LEVEL_PAGES - 1))
                 {

                         page++;
                         camera.offsetCenter(distanceX + CAMERA_WIDTH, 0);
                 }
                 else
                 {

                         camera.offsetCenter(distanceX, 0);
                 }

                    }




                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickDetector pClickDetector, int pPointerID,
                                    float pSceneX, float pSceneY) {
                             //loadLeve(levelClicked);
                    }

                     private void createHUD()
                    {
                            // 不用考虑层
                            hud = new HUD();
                            Rectangle hudBox = new Rectangle(20, 700, 80, 80, getVertexBufferObjectManager())
                            {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                                    float pTouchAreaLocalY)
                                    {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp())
                                            {
                                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                                    {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void run()
                                                            {
                                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                                    Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                    });
                                            }

                                            return true;
                                    }
                            };
                            hudBox.setColor(Color.RED);
                            hud.attachChild(hudBox);
                            hud.registerTouchArea(hudBox);
                            camera.setHUD(hud);
                    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int pKeyCode, final KeyEvent pEvent) {
                  if (pKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                            && pEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                            ) {


                                    if(level_scene){
                                      level_scene = false;
                                      camera.setCenter(camera_x, camera_y);
                                  mEngine.setScene(MainMenuScene);
                                    }else{
                                            finish();
                                    }
                                     return true;

                            }
                               return super.onKeyDown(pKeyCode, pEvent);




    }

    private void createLevelBoxes()
    {


            // 计算行间距
            int spaceBetweenRaws = (CAMERA_HEIGHT / LEVEL_ROWS_PER_SCREEN) - LEVEL_PADDING;
            // 计算列间距
            int spaceBetweenColumns = (CAMERA_WIDTH / LEVEL_COLUMNS_PER_SCREEN) - LEVEL_PADDING;

            int level = 0;

            int boxX = LEVEL_PADDING;
            int boxY = LEVEL_PADDING;

            for (int i=0; i<LEVEL_PAGES; i++)
            {
                    int startX = i * CAMERA_WIDTH;

                    for (int j=0; j<LEVEL_ROWS_PER_SCREEN; j++)
                    {
                            for (int k=0; k<LEVEL_COLUMNS_PER_SCREEN; k++)
                            {
                                    final int levelToLoad = level;
                               box = new Sprite(startX + boxX, boxY, 90,70,this.levelIcon,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager())
                                    {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                                            float pTouchAreaLocalY)
                                            {

                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                                             levelClicked = levelToLoad;
                                                           if(levelClicked <= maxLevelReached){

                                                               Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, GameLevel.class);

                                                            intent.putExtra("level", levelClicked);
                                                            startActivity(intent);
                                                            woodClick.play();
                                                           }
                                                    return false;
                                            }
                                    };


                                    if (level <= maxLevelReached)
                                    {

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                      box.setColor(0.4117647f, 0.4117647f,0.4117647f);      
                                    }

                                    levelScene.attachChild(box);
                                    levelScene.registerTouchArea(box);
                                    int textOffX = 0;
                                    if (level < 10)
                                    {
                                            textOffX = 28;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            textOffX = 20;
                                    }
                                    box.attachChild(new Text(textOffX, 20, font, String.valueOf(level + 1),this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()));


                                    level++;
                                    boxX += spaceBetweenColumns + LEVEL_PADDING;
                                    if (level > LEVELS)
                                    {
                                            break;
                                    }
                            }
                            if (level > LEVELS)
                            {
                                    break;
                            }


                            boxY += spaceBetweenRaws + LEVEL_PADDING;
                            boxX = LEVEL_PADDING;
                    }

                    boxY = LEVEL_PADDING;

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when user presses back key you have to adjust view bounds of the camera again to the current scene.